# Puppeteer get elements from a <dl> structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to get the elements in a  structure that looks like this:

```html
<dl class="foo-bar">
    <dt>Key</dt>
    <dd>Value<dd>
    <dt>Key</dt>
    <dd>Value<dd>
    ....
</dl>
```

This is what I would like to do in pure JS:

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar')

let key = list[0].children[0].innerText // would give me "Key"
```

This is where I'm at:

```js
let list = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar'), element => element))

let key = list[0] //returns empty object ({})
```

EDIT: 
I need to access all of the `dt` key/values. Preferably adding them to an object like this:

```js
let object = {
    key1: "key1",
    value1: "value1",
    key2: "key2",
    value2: "value2"
}
```

I know the structure of the object doesn't make much sense but it's not really relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking @Vaviloffs answer solved the issue!

Im simply creating an array of all the `dt` and `dd` elements with

```
let list = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar dt, .foo-bar dd'), element => element.textContent))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.foo-bar dt, .foo-bar dd` selector should get you an array of all the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements that are nested in `<dl class="foo-bar"></dl>`.

```js
const list = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar dt, .foo-bar dd'));

const key = list[0].innerText;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`$$()` page method](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pageselector-1), which is essentially `document.querySelectorAll()`. Here's an example:

```js
const list = await page.$$('.foo-bar dt, .foo-bar dd');

const key = list[0].innerText;
```

Here's an example of how you can use `reduce()` on your array to transform it into the object you need:

```js
// Stubbing the list data for example.
const list = [
  { innerText: 'key1' },
  { innerText: 'value1' },
  { innerText: 'key2' },
  { innerText: 'value2' },
  { innerText: 'key3' },
  { innerText: 'value3' }
]

const test = list.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
  // Map even items as properties and odd items as values to prev property.
  i % 2 === 0 ? acc[v.innerText] = null : acc[list[i-1].innerText] = v.innerText;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the first `dt` text, you should request it directly:

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.foo-bar dt').innerText)
```

Comment: I see that i was a bit unclear in my initial question, but have updated it now. I need access to all of the `dt` elements